# Using docker during the development workflow

Tags: node.js, docker, boot2docker

I'm using boot2docker on OS X and cloned the following repo:

https://github.com/enokd/docker-node-hello

It basically has a Dockerfile and a very simple express app that prints hello world. Everything runs great when I build  and run the image, but of course if I make any changes to index.js on my Mac none of that gets reflected in my running image. I can't seem to find any references on how I'd setup docker so that I can run it in my development environment to automatically pick up my source code changes so I feel like I'm "Doing it wrong". Any suggestions?

Here's how I'm currently running it (I'm not using Vagrant, and not quite sure if that makes any difference):

```
$ docker build -t gasi/centos-node-hello .
$ docker run -p 49160:8080 -d gasi/centos-node-hello
$ curl localhost:49160
```

*Update:* Added an answer with what I ended up doing.

*Update:* Added more current answer using boot2docker 1.3+ and fig.

Comment: I've written Docker Shell for this purpose. See http://dockershell.io/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, so far seems to work but I'm still digging into it:

```
# script located in bin/run
NS=mycompany
PROJECT=myproject

# kill and remove old container if it exists
docker kill $PROJECT
docker rm $PROJECT

# tag the previously built image
docker tag $NS/$PROJECT $NS/$PROJECT:old

# build the new image
docker build -t $NS/$PROJECT .

# remove the old image
docker rmi $NS/$PROJECT:old

docker run -dP --name=$PROJECT $NS/$PROJECT /sbin/my_init
```

In my project root, I simply run:

```
nodemon -x bin/run
```

Credit goes to this [source](http://murphyrandle.svbtle.com/vittles-for-developing-nodejs-apps-in-docker).

**Update for docker 1.3 and fig**

[Fig](http://www.fig.sh/) is great, it really took a lot of the complexity out of the script I had before. In addition, boot2docker now natively supports mounting volumes on Mac OS X using Virtual Box's shared folders. This is what I find works really well for me now:

First, the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Replace shell with bash so we can source files
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Set debconf to run non-interactively
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections

# Install base dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        git \
        libssl-dev \
        python \
        rsync \
        software-properties-common \
        wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 0.10.33

# Install nvm with node and npm
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.20.0/install.sh | bash \
    && source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The `fig.yml`:

```
app:
    image: myNodeImage
    working_dir: /home/myProject
    volumes_from:
     - myvols
```

Here's the new `bin/run`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This is the the bin/run script

docker run --rm --volumes-from myvols myNodeImage \
    rsync \
        --delete \
        --recursive \
        --safe-links \
        --exclude .git  --exclude node_modules  \
    /data/myProject/ /home/myProject

fig up
```

I also have a `bin/install` script that does the `node_modules` dependency installs. This assumes I've already done an npm install on my host so that any private packages will work. Also, this works great with npm links, you just need to make a symlink from your `/home/linkedProject` into `$NODE_PATH/linkedProject` in your container.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This is the the bin/install script

docker run --rm --volumes-from myvols myNodeImage \
    rm -rf /home/myProject && \
    rsync \
        --delete \
        --recursive \
        --safe-links \
        --exclude .git \
        /data/myProject/ /home/myProject && \
    cd /home/myProject && \
    npm rebuild
```

So, to put this all together, here's the steps in order:

1. Create my data volume container:

   `docker run -v $HOME/data:/data:ro \
               -v /home \
               -v /path/to/NODE_PATH \
               --name myvols myNodeImage echo Creating my volumes`
2. Run my install script: `cd ~/data/myProject && ./bin/install`
3. Run my run script: `nodemon -x bin/run`

Comment: interesting approach. so you think developing local and building a docker image once you want to deploy it is the way to go?

Comment: I'm actually developing inside docker as well and it's working great. It's basically a turbocharged version of what I have above, but instead of running `nodemon` directly I made a script that uses `nodemon` as a library and does a lot of things to setup the project correctly before sending it to the docker build context. This allows me to do things like pulling in dependent projects that I'm working on concurrently.

Comment: @mattes FYI, I updated the answer with something that closely approximates my current workflow.

Comment: Have you had any luck or success with using filesystem watchers in this setup?

Comment: @DavidSouther yes, I'm using `nodemon` as described above. It looks something like: `nodemon -x bin/run`

Comment: I suppose you're doing that with a linux host. No luck for us poor OSX users.

Comment: No, this is on OS X. As you can see however it's running rsync inside the container.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is really interesting, and (partially) not specifically related to Docker.
Let me say that the main and final problem here is the use of a virtual machine.

Tracking code changes on host computer can be a challenge when you use a VM (bare Virtualbox VM, Vagrant VM, Docker boot2docker VM...)

The VM is a complete layer of abstraction between your Mac (where your code changes happen) and your application stack (here, the Docker container running on a tiny Linux VM).

- You have to explicitly define a shared folder (NFS, ...) in Virtualbox, between your Mac and boot2docker. This shared folder would be the root of your code repository. That's the first step.

  *Mac*: /Users/You/stuff/approot  ===>  *boot2docker*: **/something**

- Then, you would have to tell your Docker container to use a **Volume** (docker terminology), bound to boot2docker, and point your Docker application to it:

```
   docker run -v /something:/app/path/inside/docker -p 49160:8080 \
     -d gasi/centos-node-hello /usr/bin/node /app/path/inside/docker/index.js
```

- Having NodeJs detecting files change is another challenge. You need an additional wrapper watching the filesystem and restarting Node upon code changes ([Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever), [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)...).
- And, after that since the changes don't occur on a local filesystem, but on a shared folder, you'll probably have to tell the Nodejs watcher (Forever/Nodemon/...) to use polling mode. It works (more or less) but will burn a lot of CPU.

Comment: Thanks! Vagrant does something like this automatically (the folder containing the Vagrantfile automatically gets mounted as /vagrant).

Comment: The answer I was looking for (or maybe hoping was feasible) would be something along the lines of running a watcher in the host OS that would automatically update the image (ie, re-run the ADD command somehow).

Comment: As far as I know, there's no direct/integrated solution. You would have to add a FS watcher on the host (why not Forever or Nodemon, by the way) and have it run `docker build...`, provided you have a Dockerfile containing relevant instructions. That being said, I don't think re-building an image on each file change is a good workflow. Instead, I would periodically rebuild (on git push for example) an image I could share for testing or deploy to production.

Comment: No I'm totally cool with Forever or Nodemon (I'm actually going to try to use the passenger-docker image with Passenger set to reload on every request). I just wanted to see if re-building the image anytime a file changed made sense or not. Doesn't most everything get cached anyway?

Comment: As for git push, that's not very convenient when you want to make a lot of quick, small changes and would be too disruptive.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said that in my opinion, rebuilding an image should maybe ony happen when you want to share or deploy your work : that would happen less often than after every single file edit.

Comment: And yes, almost everything would get cached, but you would end up with hundreds of cached intermediate images at the end of your day. By the way, what would be the point of rebuilding an image after each change if you don't want to deploy it?

Comment: I guess I want to have my cake and eat it too :) Ideally, my container running in development would be as close as possible to my container running in prod. So if my development just had a host-side watcher that updated the image (instead of using a separate mounted location that prod would not use) that would be perfect.

Comment: I understand, basically I'm also more or less interested by the same exact workflow as your. Still not sure if what you want makes sense (continuously rebuilding a container on each code change). Or maybe use the container to have the same exact environment for dev & prod (system, services & apps), but keep the code separated on a Docker volume on both dev & prod.

Comment: Answered this question with what I ended up doing, would love to hear any feedback you might have.

Comment: Great discussion. There is some more discussion about app development workflows with docker going on here: http://goo.gl/tc43UH Also, Solomon  is developing IN a container as well: https://twitter.com/solomonstre/status/481614513054052355 My opinion is: `docker run` services you don't develop features for like redis, postgres, RabbitMQ, ... For the development of your main business logic, stick to your trusted package managers (pip, gems, ...)

Answer (score 5):

Concerning shared folders with VirtualBox, please check out:

**boot2docker together with VirtualBox Guest Additions**
How to mount /Users into boot2docker

https://medium.com/boot2docker-lightweight-linux-for-docker/boot2docker-together-with-virtualbox-guest-additions-da1e3ab2465c

> tl;dr Build your own custom boot2docker.iso with VirtualBox Guest
>   Additions (see [link](https://gist.github.com/mattes/2d0ffd027cb16571895c#file-readme-md)) or download
>   http://static.dockerfiles.io/boot2docker-v1.1.0-virtualbox-guest-additions-v4.3.12.iso
>   and save it to ~/.boot2docker/boot2docker.iso.

EDIT: updated link to boot2docker v1.1.0

Comment: will be nice to have a link somewhere to your latest iso instead of v1.0.1 since it will be changed with time going on

Answer (score 0):

There's several scenarios that docker can help on web development:

1. lighting fast provision all different kinds of services locally. you want a clean couchdb, run `docker run -d -p 5984:5984 tutum/couchdb`; mysql, no problem: `docker run -d -p 3306:3306 tutum/mysql`, a selenium server with firefox? easy: `sudo docker run -p 4444:4444 -d lzhang/selenium`, you will get them immediately, and they can be destroyed by `docker kill` the next seconds you don't want them. fit the local testing scenario very well, no need to worry how to configure them.
2. manage software dependencies. for example, you want to run your node app under different node versions (0.8, 0.10, 0.10.25, etc), just find the nodejs docker images by `docker search nodejs`, and create containers by mounting your application directory as volume, you can run multiple containers which is isolated to each other. Take a look at my [keystonejs-example](https://github.com/shawnzhu/keystonejs-example) project on how to run a complicated node app with mongodb in seconds with 0 configuration. thinking a more complicated model: load balancer + app + database + cache, in old school way, there're tons of configuration options to fit the setup procedure, but, if you provision them as separate containers and [link them by names](http://docs.docker.io/use/working_with_links_names/), every components can discover each other by local environment variables, just like a local PaaS.
3. an easy way to use application by searching [docker index](https://index.docker.io/). for example, there is a neat tool called [Heartbleed checker](https://github.com/kasimon/docker-heartbleed), you can quickly download/use it in a container with ready configuration by a single command, even don't need to think about config, download language runtime, configure, uninstall, etc.

Per boot2docker, I assume you're on OSX, so you'd better pickup version v0.9.2+ which supports hostonly network configuration, then you can access the containers run inside the VM over the hostonly network.

Comment: I'm aware of the 3 features you listed and they are great features but my question really had nothing to do with that. I'm really interested in how iterative development can be done in a docker environment. How I can make a change in my text editor or IDE and see my docker environment reflect that.