# Rebuild when files changes on docker

Tags: go, docker, boot2docker

i'm starting to work with docker (with boot2docker on Mac OSX) and golang,

Whenever I make changes on my .go files I want to be visible on the docker image.

Is there anyway to do this? Or docker is not the appropiate thing to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker does not do this by default. I described a couple approaches to this in my question & answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796772/using-docker-during-the-development-workflow). A simple way to accomplish what you want is to use a watcher (like nodemon) to monitor your folder and kick off a script (or better, use fig) that recreates and runs your images.